# SQL record retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, eloquent

Good day community,

I need help to retrieve record from mysql table as seen below. Please note my targeted results:

[image: Table and result]

Below is my current approach which works well on small number of rows but extremely slow or time our on thousands even hundreds of rows.

```
public function usersTopRecruits(){
    $tempUID = array();
    $mainAssocArr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < User::count(); $i++) { 
        if($i == 0){
            $offset = 0;
        }
        else{           
            $offset = $this->take * $i;
        }

        $users = User::take($this->take)->offset($offset)->get();

        foreach ($users as $value) {
            $refCnts = User::where('referral', $value->aff_id)->count();

            if($refCnts > 0){
                $tempUID['userAffID'] = $value->aff_id;
                $tempUID['userrecruits'] = $refCnts;
                $mainAssocArr[] = $tempUID;
            }
        }
    }//End of For loop

    //Here, i tried to sort by highest recruits

    foreach ($mainAssocArr as $key => $row) {
        $desc[$key]  = $row['userrecruits'];
        $asc[$key] = $row['userAffID'];
    }

    array_multisort($desc, SORT_DESC, $asc, SORT_ASC, $mainAssocArr);

    return $mainAssocArr;
}
```

The Current month:

```
public function userTopRecruitsCurrMonth(){
    $tempUID = array();
    $mainAssocArr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < User::count(); $i++) { 
        if($i == 0){
            $offset = 0;
        }
        else{           
            $offset = $this->take * $i;
        }

        $users = User::take($this->take)->offset($offset)->get();

        foreach ($users as $value) {
            $refCnts = User::where('referral', $value->aff_id)->where('signup_date', '>=', 'startDateOfCurrentMonth')->count();

            if($refCnts > 0){
                $tempUID['userAffID'] = $value->aff_id;
                $tempUID['userRecruits'] = $refCnts;
                $mainAssocArr[] = $tempUID;
            }
        }
    }//End of For loop


    foreach ($mainAssocArr as $key => $row) {
        $volume[$key]  = $row['userRecruits'];
        $edition[$key] = $row['userAffID'];
    }

    array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $mainAssocArr);

    return $mainAssocArr;
}
```

Any assistance or suggestion would be appreciated.

NOTE: I am using Eloquent model but NOT using "laravel"

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? Do you want an SQL query?

Comment: Yea, query builders.  Sorry I'm not a fan of them.  Personally I would probably do a (correlated) subquery to count the totals and then join to that to do the ordering.  It's an aggregate query that has to count the whole DB, if you can bake in the number and maintain it, it will be much faster.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for the comment. any example query or subquery you think can solve or be helpful to solve the problems?

Comment: Yes, [DbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQuhkTcRQFud5nigqwdFzS/0) if you want users without referrals you may have to do a Left Join instead of an Inner Join (Join)

Comment: The subquery is there if you want things like the First Name etc.  As grouping on the `referral` would instead give you one of those refered users Data and not the actual users data. It's better to do it as a subquery because it builds a smaller temp table then doing it all in the same level, it also does the sorting on the smaller temp table.  You can even move the ORDER BY to the subquery, and it wont change anything.  [For Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQuhkTcRQFud5nigqwdFzS/1)  At least as far as I understand how it optimizes things.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix this is helpful, big thanks to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment I understand that providing you with SQL queries could help.

This simple aggragated query will return the `REFERRAL`s with most occurences (all time), highest on top.

```
SELECT referral, COUNT(*) 
FROM table
GROUP BY referral
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you are looking for the same results for the current month, then just add a `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT referral, COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(sigmup_date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(sigmup_date) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY referral
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: your answer look great but the current month part seems no working from the <where> condition

Comment: @HarrisonOziegbe : correct, I misorderd the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses.  Edited my answer, it should work fine now.

Comment: Welcome @HarrisonOziegbe, glad it helped out !

Answer (score 1):

I would use a query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users AS u0 
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        u1.REFERRAL AS agg,
        COUNT(u1.REFERRAL) AS total
    FROM 
        users AS u1
    GROUP BY
        u1.REFERRAL
    ORDER BY total DESC
) AS u2
ON
    u2.agg = u0.AFF_ID
```

The subquery allows you, by joining with the table again, to pull out data on the actual users who's AFF_ID is being grouped on.  This will give you things like their FIRST_NAME etc. Where if you didn't join again you won't get that stuff.

It also builds a smaller temp (in memory) table then if you did it on the same level (possibly, I would have to dig into it with explain more).

[Try it yourself](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQuhkTcRQFud5nigqwdFzS/1)

If you want to do it for just one Month we can modify the subquery to count only users added that month:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users AS u0 
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        u1.REFERRAL AS agg,
        COUNT(u1.REFERRAL) AS total
    FROM 
        users AS u1
    WHERE 
        YEAR(u1.sigmup_date) = YEAR(NOW())
      AND
        MONTH(u1.sigmup_date) = MONTH(NOW())
    GROUP BY
        u1.REFERRAL
    ORDER BY total DESC
) AS u2
ON
    u2.agg = u0.AFF_ID
```

Lastly you may/will have to use a LEFT JOIN, if you want users that have not referred anyone.

[For Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQuhkTcRQFud5nigqwdFzS/2)

And if you add something like

```
WHERE
  u2.agg IS NULL
```

To the end of the outer query you can find all users with no referrals.

[For Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQuhkTcRQFud5nigqwdFzS/3)

Any optimization aside, it reads better (to me) to do it as a sub-query.

Last one, if you don't like NULL for the total you can use `COALESCE()` to fix that like this:

```
SELECT
  u0.*, COALESCE(u2.total,0) AS total
FROM
  users AS u0 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
      u1.REFERRAL AS agg,
      COUNT(u1.REFERRAL) AS total
  FROM 
      users AS u1
  GROUP BY
      u1.REFERRAL
  ORDER BY total DESC
) AS u2
ON
  u2.agg = u0.AFF_ID
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQuhkTcRQFud5nigqwdFzS/4)

And now those are 0's

I find `COALESCE` to be very useful and the less work you have to do in code, the easier things will be. If you can format the data the way you want from the DB, it's generally better then manipulating it latter.  It can be the difference between using something like `fetchAll` and having to loop though it and modify it in PHP before you can even use it.

Cheers!